# Django AttributeError: 'InterestsForm' object has no attribute '_errors'

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

I am trying to use a Django form to allow a Django User to input their three favourite interests. The error occurs during the template rendering where it says `{{form.as_ul}}`.

Here is the code:

**reg_interests.html**

```
{% block content %}

<br><br>
<h1>Choose the 3 things that interest you most!</h1>

<form method="post" action="/reg_interests/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_ul}}
    <br>
    <p class="submit"><input  class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="commit" value="Continue"></p>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def reg_interests_view(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = InterestsForm(request.POST, request=request)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(request)
            return redirect('/reg_video/')

    args = {}
    args['form'] = InterestsForm(request=request)

    return render(request, 'login/reg_interests.html', args)
```

**forms.py**

```
class InterestsForm(RequestModelForm):
    interest1 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1, "Option 1"), (2, "Option 2")])
    interest2 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1, "Option 1"), (2, "Option 2")])
    interest3 = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(1, "Option 1"), (2, "Option 2")])

    class Meta:
        model = Interest
        fields = ('interest1', 'interest2', 'interest3')

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.user = request.user

    def save(self, commit=True):
        interest = super(InterestsForm, self).save(commit=False)
        interest.user = self.user
        interest.interest1 = self.cleaned_data['interest1']
        interest.interest2 = self.cleaned_data['interest2']
        interest.interest3 = self.cleaned_data['interest3']

        if commit:
            interest.save()

        return interest
```

I think there is a problem with the form, but I don't know how or why I need to define `_errors`. Should Django itself not take care of that? If not, how do I define `_errors`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code can't possibly work at all, because you override the `__init__` method of the form so that a) you only accept a `request` argument - and not any of the other things a form is expecting, like `data` or `initial` - and b) you never call the superclass init method to initialise the things the rest of the form code expects. You need to preserve the signature and call super.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     request = kwargs.pop('request')
     self.user = request.user
     super(InterestsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you! I would never have figured that out.